# how to make a bullet shoot diagonally in flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, angle, diagonal

I have been having this problem for ages and haven't found a solution for this.

Well in flash I have a character who's gun position is similar to this

http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/chudtsankov/chudtsankov1004/chudtsankov100400927/6906625-cartoon-character-mobster-carries-weapon.jpg

I have been having difficulties in try to shoot the bullet  in the same angle as the gun is pointing. I've tried working with angles but it just doesn't seem to be working.

Right now, the bullet is shooting straight up but i want it to shoot in an angle.

So far I have this

```
function shootBullet():void {

    var fire:myBullet2 = new myBullet2();
    fire.x = GirlHero.x;
    fire.y = GirlHero.y;
    addChild(fire);
    fire.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBullet);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you! :) By the way, my character is controlled by the left,right and up key, The up key is to shoot and the left is to walk left and right to walk right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good example of this at:-

http://rhuno.com/flashblog/2011/11/18/calculating-angles-and-moving-objects-accordingly/

You want to do something like

```
var angle:int = 270;
var rads:Number = angle*Math.PI/180;
var speed:int = 2;

function moveBullet(e:Event)
{
  e.currentTarget.x += Math.cos(rads) * speed;  
  e.currentTarget.y += Math.sin(rads) * speed;  
}
```

You'll need to set angle accordingly depending on which way the character is facing (if it flips)

Comment: Hiya. Thanks for you time but it still doesn't seem to be working. I tried something similar to the code that you have given but its still giving me trouble. Thank you for your time. I will keep digging.

Comment: OMG THANK YOU! I played about with the code and i got it to work!!!!!!!! THANK YOU SOO MUCH!